# how i get the all the details of product from product id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woo-commerce

i am having the product id and i need the specific details of that product lik short description,product feature image,price,and the link of product detail page.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [the WooCommerce functions documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product.html)?

You can use `wc_get_product()` to return product details as a `WC_Product` object.

For example:

```
$product = get_product( $product_id );
```

Comment: Thanks for this i get the title and description but did not get the featured image and price with this

Answer (score 0):

try to look at the default product detail page. it will have some code or global variables, you can use them to get the details.

look at the functions file to get the product details.